# oData v3 setting $format to application/json;odata=verbose doesn't convert to old json format

Tags: json, odata, backbone.paginator

I'm working on a backbone.js app that GET the odata format from the controller:

```
  public IQueryable<ContactList> Get()
  {
     return dbContext.ContactsList.AsQueryable();
  }
```

But the way I receive the data is in the following format

```
odata.count: "15504"
odata.metadata: "http://localhost:53341/odata/$metadata#Prescribers"
odata.nextLink: "http://localhost:53341/odata/Prescribers?$inlinecount=allpages&$format=application%2Fjson%3Bodata%3Dverbose
value: [,…]
```

Note the $format. Despite setting this up, it keeps sending me data in odata v3 format. I also tested it in Fiddler, but still the same result.

Am I doing something wrong? I'm trying to use the data for Backbone paginator https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator

Answer (score 0):

I don't think webapi.odata v3 supports $format.

But you can try setting the accept header with `application/json;...`

If you want to use `$format` in the url, you can call "AddQueryStringMapping" to map `$format`, check this:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/odata-feed-using-Asp-Net-web-api/

Comment: No.. that didn't help either.